# How do you extract the underlying Bitmap from an ImageView with RenderEffect?

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, renderscript

I've been looking into applying blur to a `Bitmap` via `ImageView` using [RenderEffect](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/graphics/RenderEffect#createBlurEffect(kotlin.Float,%20kotlin.Float,%20android.graphics.RenderEffect,%20android.graphics.Shader.TileMode)). I'm able to do so through [setRenderEffect](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setRenderEffect(android.graphics.RenderEffect)). However, when I try to get `Bitmap` out of the `ImageView`,  using the below (hacky) code, it does not have the blur applied to it. I believe this is because the layer is applied but not to the underlying bitmap in the ImageView (not 100% certain). This leads me to the question of: how do you get the underlying Bitmap associated with an ImageView that is rendered on the screen after RenderEffect has been applied?

```
        val testImageView = ImageView(applicationContext)
        testImageView.setImageBitmap(someBitmap)
        val blurEffect = RenderEffect.createBlurEffect(30.0f, 30.0f, Shader.TileMode.MIRROR)
        testImageView.setRenderEffect(blurEffect)
        testImageView.invalidate()
        val testDrawable = testImageView.drawable as BitmapDrawable
        val testBitmap = testDrawable.getBitmap(); // This doesn't have Blur applied to it even though I'd like it to.
```

Using [RenderScript](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/renderscript/ScriptIntrinsicBlur) looks possible but it's been deprecated past API 31, so I've been looking for an alternative.

Comment: did you find a solution for this? Having thet same issue. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't. I ended up using RenderScript and plan on using the external tooling as needed.

Answer (score 0):

As render effects are applied only on drawing, you need to draw your entire ImageView to Canvas to see the blurred result. The next code might be helpful:

```kotlin
fun getBitmapWithBlur(imageView: ImageView): Bitmap {
    val bitmapWithBlur = Bitmap.createBitmap(imageView.width, imageView.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
    val canvas = Canvas(bitmapWithBlur)
    imageView.draw(canvas)
    return bitmapWithBlur
}
```